# Node logging uncaught exception (Winston V3)

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, winston

I'm new to Winston, and I'm trying to use it to log uncaught exceptions and then exit. It is logging to the console, but doesn't seem to have time to log to a file before exiting

Here is an example:

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const logger = require('./startup/logging');

process.on('uncaughtException', (ex) => {
    logger.error("Won't be logged in the File");
    process.exit(1);
});

throw new Error("Uncaught");
```

logging.js

```
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');

const logger = createLogger({     
    format: format.combine(
        format.timestamp({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss |'
        }),
        format.printf(info => `${info.timestamp} ${info.level}: ${info.message}`)
    ),
    transports: [
        new transports.Console({
            format: format.combine(
                format.colorize({
                    // all: true
                }),
                // this is repeated because for some reason colorize() won't work otherwise
                format.printf(info => `${info.timestamp} ${info.level}: ${info.message}`)            
            )
        }),
        new transports.File({ filename: './exceptions.log' })
    ]
});

module.exports = logger;
```

As mentioned, the uncaught exception is logged to the console, but not to the file. Removing `process.exit(1)` solves the problem of logging, but I do want the program to exit.

Adding `handleExceptions: true` to the File transport causes the same issue - it exits prior to logging the exception. I'm assuming this is the cause, as adding `exitOnError: false` then logs the exception.

Is this the intended behaviour? It seems strange to me, even as a beginner.

EDIT:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', (ex) => {
    logger.log('error', 'Will be logged');
    setTimeout(function(){process.exit(1)}, 1000);
});
```

This works, but surely isn't a fix, just shows the problem i'm having

Comment: setting a timeout of a second for `process.exit(1)` solves the issue - but surely isn't ideal

Answer (score 1):

`logging.error` is probably an IO (async) operation and yields after invocation:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', (ex) => {
    logger.error("Won't be logged in the File"); # registers operation with node event loop and continues
    process.exit(1);
});
```

The [node documentation shows](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception) a synchronous write but I am not sure of how to plug this in to winston:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
  fs.writeSync(1, `Caught exception: ${err}\n`);
  process.exit(1)
});
```

Comment: unfortunately, neither am i. above my knowledge level.

Answer (score 1):

What version are you using? In v2 you could use a [callback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18790117/56151) that executes after the log entry has been written.

```
process.on('uncaughtException', (ex) => {
    logger.error("Will be logged in the File", function() {
        process.exit(1);
    });
});
```

In v3 you're [supposed to do](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.0.md#winstonlogger):

```
logger.log('info', 'some message');
logger.on('finish', () => process.exit());
logger.end();
```

Comment: it's so weird. the callback doesn't seem to work unless you call 'logger.end()', but the code only then works *once*.

Comment: Which callback? `onFinish`? That would make sense, wouldn't it? You only need it to be called once so that you don't exit the process until the logs are flushed.

Comment: No I mean it only seemed to work the first time when adding the call to end(), if at all. And i think that was coincidence. Restarting the server and experiencing another exception logs nothing. Having looked at the link below i dont think it's the solution to the problem unfortunately, but i guess i could be implementing it wrong

Answer (score 1):

A good read on the problem spanning 2013 to date.

https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/228

There are various work arounds mentioned, but it doesn't look like this is ever going to be fixed. Which is annoying. Going to look at log4js-node instead, which has apparently addressed this.