# Cannot get the logger (winston) to create a log file

Tags: node.js, fs, winston

I went through many of the answered related to Winston, but I cannot find what my problem (code) is

```
const winston = require('winston');
const fs = require('fs');

const logDir = `./logs/`;
if (!fs.existsSync(logDir)) {
  fs.mkdirSync(logDir);
}

console.log(`logDir: ${logDir}`);

/* https://github.com/winstonjs/winston */
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  format: winston.format.json(),
  exitOnError: false,
  transports: [
    //
    // - Write to all logs with level `info` and below to `combined.log`
    // - Write all logs error (and below) to `error.log`.
    //
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: `${logDir}/error-${process.pid}.log`,
                                  level: 'error',
                                  format: winston.format.combine(
                                    winston.format.timestamp(),
                                    winston.format.json(),
                                  )
                               }),
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: `${logDir}/combined-${process.pid}.log`,
                                  format: winston.format.combine(
                                    winston.format.timestamp(),
                                    winston.format.json(),
                                  )
                               }),

  ]
});

logger.info('info test');
logger.warn('warn test');
logger.error('error test');

const combinedLogs = logger.transports.find(transport => {
 console.log(`transport.filename: ${transport.filename}, transport.dirname: ${transport.dirname}`);
 // console.log(`transport: ${util.inspect(transport)}`);
});

process.exit(0);
```

The output when I run with nodejs (v10.15.3) is:

```
# nodejs myscript.js
logDir: ./logs/
transport.filename: error-24238.log, transport.dirname: ./logs/
transport.filename: combined-24238.log, transport.dirname: ./logs/
```

But nothing is present in the logs dir:

```
root@someserver:/usr/local/somepath# ls -l logs/
total 0
```

I am using winston and fs:

```
+ winston@3.2.1
+ fs@0.0.1-security
```

Comment: [How to flush winston logs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18771707/2313887). Noting that not all transports should be expected to fire in a synchronous manner. You should wait for the logger to tell you all are actually done.

Comment: I don't quite get your link relevance, process.exit(0) is a valid case here - its not an exception, there is no exception happening (which is what the link discusses about) or a callback. so the proposed solutions in the link won't work here. @NeilLunn

Comment: The "relevance" is the logging is asynchronous. You are exiting the program before anything gets written.

Comment: Thanks @NeilLunn - I figured that was the problem, now I am looking for a solution - I tired 'winston-log-and-exit' as well, but it doesn't seem to work on latest nodejs version / winston (apparently the design was changed)