# Any logger supporting sync log writing?

Tags: node.js, winston

I have tried to use Winston logger as it seems to be the most popular choice for the task. However I am having problems when using it in scenarios when I would like to write the exception log and exit the process, e.g. when handling the `uncaughtException` event

```
process.once("uncaughtException", (err) => {
  logger.error(err);
  process.exit(1);
});
```

the problem here is that the logger has no time to complete the task as it's doing it async, and the log will never be logged. In addition to this, I believe we should exit as soon as possible and not add anything into the loop anyway.
Do you know how to implement this idea?

Comment: This looks relevant: [How to flush Winston logs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18771707/how-to-flush-winston-logs).

Comment: Yeah, but it isn't working. The callback is never called.

Comment: Are you calling `process.exit()` BEFORE the callback is called?  You don't show any code that illustrates what's in that other answer so we can't see what it is you say you're trying that isn't working.

Comment: process.once("uncaughtException", (err) => {
        logger.log('error', 'Fatal uncaught exception crashed cluster', err, 
            function(err: any, level: any, msg: any, meta: any) {

            process.exit(1);
        });
});